# jquery bind not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I've a problem binding a click event with jquery. It's working fine in all browsers but not in Firefox. Thanks in advance for your answer.

```
var conf_markers = function() {

        // create a wrapper for our markers
        $m_wrapper = $('<ol class="bjqs-markers"></ol>');

        // for every slide, create a marker
        $.each($slides, function(key, slide){

            var slidenum    = key + 1,
                gotoslide   = key + 1;

            if(settings.animtype === 'slide'){
                // + 2 to account for clones
                gotoslide = key + 2;
            }

            var marker = $('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');

            // set the first marker to be active
            if(slidenum === state.currentslide){ marker.addClass('active-marker'); }

            // bind the click event
            marker.bind('click','a',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if(!state.animating && state.currentslide !== gotoslide){
                    go(false,gotoslide);
                }
            });

            // add the marker to the wrapper
            marker.appendTo($m_wrapper);

        });

        $m_wrapper.appendTo($wrapper);
        $m_markers = $m_wrapper.find('li');

        // center the markers
        if (settings.centermarkers) {
            $m_wrapper.addClass('h-centered');
            var offset = (settings.width - $m_wrapper.width()) / 2;
            $m_wrapper.css('left', offset);
        }

    };
```

The line marker.bind('click','a',function(e){ is the one causing this for as far as I can see.

Comment: Have you tried to use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`?

Comment: Thanks for the veeery fast reply, just tried but didn't help actually .on() didn't work in any browser

Comment: Maybe you are using a lower version of jquery.

Comment: Aaaah I was using 1.6.4, now using 1.7.1 and the Original function is working now

Comment: .on() is also working now and since that's the new way I'll use that. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the line

```
marker.bind('click','a',function(e){
```

with this

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
marker.on('click', 'a', function(e){
```

Since, the links are added dynamically, you need to use event delegation to register the event handler using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).